# R Partial string match and returns a value from the matched row (like "match" in excel)

Tags: r, string-matching, grepl

I would like to ask you if there is a similar function like "match" in excel in R.

For example if I have a dataset with people's educational degrees:

```
> edu
chr [1:4] "Bachelor" "NA" "Master" "Superieur"
```

And an international mapping system by ISCED:

```
> ISCED
 Main education program                      English translation                   Code
 Brevet d'enseignement supérieur (BES)       certificate of higher education        5
 bachelier de transition                     Bachelor                               6
 Bachelor                                    Bachelor                               6
 Master                                      Master                                 7
```

I wonder if there is a function that can help identify partially the strings from the vector edu from the first column of the dataframe ISCED, and then if there is a match, the code (5, 6 or 7) will be returned.

I know there are functions like "%like%" or "grepl", but I am looking for something that can skim through all values of the vector edu and not just one particular string defined each time.

Does anybody have any insights? Or would you guys suggest using a loop with the "grepl"?

Thank you!

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: If there is a match, returns the value of the "Code" and not the entire column.

Comment: Have a look at `pmatch`.

Comment: You want to match them partially, right ? and not an exact match.

Comment: Yes just the partial match since the data sources are not the same so very difficult to have an exact match.

Comment: @Imo Thanks but pmatch only returns the position or NA. But I would like to have the value in the third column to be returned when there is a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, is using `grep`.

Making a vector of strings with `paste0` and getting an index wherever it matches the first column (`Main_education_group`). Using that index to fetch the respective `Code` from the data frame.

```
ISCED$Code[grep(paste0(edu, collapse = "|"), ISCED$Main_education_program)]

#[1] 6 7
```

**EDIT**

To get the updated output as per OP's request we can use `sapply` and loop over ever element in `edu` and check of it is present or not in `Main_education_program`

```
sapply(edu, function(x) if(length(grep(x, ISCED$Main_education_program)) > 0) 
                         ISCED$Code[grep(x, ISCED$Main_education_program)] else NA)
```

which returns

```
#  Bachelor        NA    Master  Superieur 
#        6         NA         7        NA
```

If we need it without the names we can wrap it in `unname`

```
unname(sapply(edu, function(x) if(length(grep(x, ISCED$Main_education_program))>0) 
                  ISCED$Code[grep(x, ISCED$Main_education_program)] else NA ))

#[1]  6 NA  7 NA
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak! However I have a minor issue this way I would not be able to know which observations are the 6 and 7 referring to? Maybe I should let the NAs be returned as well?

Comment: @user95902 okay so do you need output to be of length `edu` ? Like in this case output should be `6 NA 7 NA`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really appreciated. The fact is the input vector 'edu' is much complicated than the 4 examples listed, and I have found that nor does 'grep' or 'grepl' work very well with '|' '()' in the pattern.

Comment: I wanted to vote up to your answer but I don't have enough repitations...sorry man